# How to print list of even numbers using Python

Tags: python, printing

I'm trying to write a python program that will prompt the user for an integer greater than 1 and reads those integers into a list followed by producing two lists and returning those values. Where should I start?

A list titled "listOfNumbers" has been created. I need to  produce a new list that only contains integers from listOfNumbers that have even induces in listOfNumbers.

```
def make_a_list(*listOfNumbers):
    for x in numList:
        if x % 2 == 0:
        print x
        listOfNumbers.append(x)

print(make_a_list(4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 11, 10, -12, -18, 1, 0)
```

I excepted a list that has the user type in a series of numbers but I'm not sure how this will turn out.

Comment: try ``listOfNumbers[1::2]``

Comment: Shouldn't `numList` be `listOfNumbers`?

Comment: I'm still fairly new to python so I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: Also, what is your expected output

Comment: @Jab I'm trying to answer a homework question that will ultimately print both lists. I need to call a function getEvenNumbers that: produces a new list that only contains integers from listOfNumbers that are even and returns the newList.

Answer (score 0):

As @geckos pointed out you can just use indexing to specify this range. Supposing we have:

```
my_list = [4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 11, 10, -12, -18, 1, 0]
```

And we want evens using a counting scheme of `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...]`, then we would call:

```
print(my_list[1::2])
```

Outputting:

```
[5, 7, 11, -12, 1]
```

This is because you specify the index as `[start:stop:step size]` but normally the step size is omitted, and therefore defaults to 1.

If instead you mean a counting scheme of `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...]` then just adjust the index to `[::2]`

Note you can also use negative step sizes. For instance:

```
print(my_list[::-1])
```

Outputs the list in reverse order, or:

```
[0, 1, -18, -12, 10, 11, 9, 7, 6, 5, 4]
```

To put it into a function would look like:

```
def make_a_list(input_list):
    even_index_list = input_list[1::2]
    return even_index_list
```

Answer (score 0):

this will give you the list of all even numbers

```
def make_a_list(*listOfNumbers):
    even_list =[]
    for num in listOfNumbers:
        if num%2==0:
            even_list.append(num)
    return even_list
print(make_a_list(4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 11, 10, -12, -18, 1, 0))
# output [4, 6, 10, -12, -18, 0]
```

this will give you numbers at even indices

```
def even_indices(*listOfNumbers):
    return listOfNumbers[2::2]


print(even_indices(4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 11, 10, -12, -18, 1, 0))
# output (6, 9, 10, -18, 0)
```

Comment: I don't think OP wants even numbers, but instead even *indexed* numbers. To quote OP "that have even *induces* in listOfNumbers"

Comment: @Reedinationer in comment he mentioned" produces a new list that only contains integers from listOfNumbers that are even and returns the newList."

Comment: It could be made simpler: `def make_a_list(*listOfNumbers):
  return [x for x in listOfNumbers if x%2==0]
`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I'm sorry if I was unclear. I just need a code that will return the values from two lists.

Comment: @tonypdmtr i wrote it this way keeping in mind that OP is a beginner in python

Comment: @Exodus1426 yoou need to better explain, if you can't descibe it a image diagram  or assignment statement would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Use range() to increment by two while looping.

```
def make_a_list(*listOfNumbers):
    output_list = []
    for i in range(0, len(listOfNumbers), 2):
        output_list.append(listOfNumbers[i])
    return output_list
```